# is it possible to use azure managed disks with azure scale sets, as an OS disk

Tags: azure

is it possible to make virtual machine scale set using manged disk. 
i am trying this in vmss vm profile but keep getting error

```
"virtualMachineProfile":{
    "storageProfile":{
        "imageReference":{
            "publisher":"Canonical",
            "offer":"UbuntuServer",
            "sku":"14.04.2-LTS",
            "version":"14.04.2-LTS"
        },
        "osDisk":{
            "osType":"Linux",
            "caching":"ReadWrite",
            "createOption":"FromImage",
            "name":"OSDisk",
            "managedDisk":{
                "storageAccountType":"Premium_LRS"
            }
        },
        "dataDisks": [{
            "lun":0,
            "managedDisk":{
                "id":
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', 'testvm_OsDisk_1_bac5bcaf20ec4cafbb0f452d631fe68f')]"
            },
            "caching":"None",
            "createOption":"Attach"
        }]
    },
    message ": " Parameter 'osDisk.managedDisk.id' is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give your osdisk a name, e.g. for osdisk:

```
"storageProfile": {
    "osDisk": {
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "caching": "ReadWrite"
    },
    "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]""
},
```

e.g. for data disks:

```
"dataDisks": [{
    "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDiskInGB')]",
    "lun": 0,
    "createOption": "Empty"
}],
```

Comment: i think this is assuming creation of images in scale set? I want to use managed disk or their snapshot and attach them as os disk to each vm that comes up.

Comment: i think i have got the answer here ? http://derekmartin.org/arm-templates-and-managed-disks/

Answer (score 0):

For now, we can't use managed disk to create Azure VM directly.
But we can create a managed image of managed vm or a snapshot via PowerShell, after that we can use this new image to create azure VM.

```
$vmName = "myVM" 
$rgName = "myResourceGroup" 
$location = "EastUS" 
$imageName = "myImage"
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName -Force
Set-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName -Generalized
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$image = New-AzureRmImageConfig -Location $location -SourceVirtualMachineId $vm.ID 
New-AzureRmImage -Image $image -ImageName $imageName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
```

[image]

More information about generalize vm and create image, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource).

By the way, the comment you added is right, we can use image in this way.